# OnClick Android method to display database data

Tags: java, php, android, html, mysql

I have an Android app that connects to a database and can update relevant data and then display it to a website in the form of a table, what I want to do is have it only display certain data when a certain a button is clicked in the app, and different data when a different button is clicked. Is this possible? I've included the Java OnClick method below along with the PHP/MySQL code to connect and display all the data. So when OpenUpdateBed1 is clicked I'd like it to display the data on bed 1 only and when OpenUpdateBed2 is clicked it should remove the data for bed 1 from website and display the data for bed 2. The fields at the top of the PHP are left blank for my own privacy, they're not causing an issue.

```
public void OpenUpdateBed1 (View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Register.class));
}
public void OpenUpdateBed2(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Register2.class));
}
```

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                       
    $servername = "";                                                                                                                               
    $username = "";                                                                                                                         
    $password = "";                                                                                                                                 
    $database = "";                                                                                                                 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){                                                                                                                            
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                       

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);                                                                                       

    if ($conn->connect_error) {                                                                                                                             
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                       

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){                                                                                                                             
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                       

    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM patients2");                                                                                                 

    echo "<table border = 5>";                                                                                                                              
    echo "<tr>";                                                                                                                                        
        echo "<th>ID</th>                                               
        <th>Patient name</th>       
        <th>Doctor name</th>                                        
        <th>Check in date</th>
        <th>Room number</th>
        <th>Bed number</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Time</th>";
    echo "</tr>";


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){                                                                                                              
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['patient_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['doctor_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['check_in_date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['room_number'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['bed_number'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($db);                                                                                                                                      
?>
```

Comment: It's possible. What you're looking for is a REST API implemented in a WAMP (Windows Apache MySQL PHP) stack. [Here is a link that shows implementation on PHP side](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/) and on android side you will need to use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) to send a request.

Comment: I'm using an online database, not a WAMP server. Does this still work?

Comment: Yes, of course. If your website is up and running the android device will send a HTTPRequest to it and the php will return the data from the db that it's connected to. What you're looking for is a REST API for php. I would do a sample, but I'm only familiar with MEAN stack.

Comment: Okay so am I correct in saying that I program the rest API in a PHP file and upload it to my site, then connect the app to that uploaded file via a HTTPUrlConnection?

Comment: Yes, you should have functions that take in URLs so 'yoursite/api/getbeds' will get beds. There's a lot of tutorials and examples online. I'm 100% sure you need a REST API.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll look into setting up a REST API